# Mutliple imagesLoaded functions css call issue

Tags: javascript, css

My preloader doesnt show when I have two function using Imagesloaded. Works fine when I disable imagesloaded on one. Need to have ablity to use three or four depending.

My preloader div and SCSS.

```
<div class="masonry-loading">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>

.masonry-loading {padding:10% 0 10% 50%;}
img {border:0 !important;}
```

Here is my function for different columns.

```
// Masonary
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('.masonry-c');
    var min_width = 230;
    $('.masonry-c').hide();
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.masonry-c').fadeIn('fast');
        $("div.masonry-loading").css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.masonry-box',
            isAnimated: true,
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                var box_width = (((containerWidth) / 3) | 0);

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = (((containerWidth) / 2) | 0);
                }

                $('.masonry-box').width(box_width);

                return box_width;
            }
        });
    });
});

// Masonary
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container1 = $('.masonry-four-c');
    var min_width = 200;
    $('.masonry-four-c').hide();
    $container1.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.masonry-four-c').fadeIn('fast');
        $container1.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.masonry-four-box',
            isAnimated: true,
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                var box_width = (((containerWidth) / 4) | 0);

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = (((containerWidth) / 3) | 0);
                }
                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = (((containerWidth) / 2) | 0);
                }

                $('.masonry-four-box').width(box_width);

                return box_width;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Below I placed the CSS to remove loader, for some reason this does not work when I load it in the function above after imagesLoaded. Perhaps if I could get that work, it would solve the problem.

```
function triggerCallback() {
    callback.call($this, $images),
    $("div.masonry-loading").css({'display': 'none'});
}
```

Tried a bunch of stuff, I bet it something simple. Anyway help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried 
$("div.masonry-loading").css("display", "none");

Comment: Add jsfiddle sample please.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
$('myelement').load(function(){
//when your element / img is loaded then this code will run.
//hide/show whatever u want
});
```